# Conditional formatting for dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to come up with a simple conditional format formula for highlighting cells that have a date that is greater than three months older than today's date.  It seems though that the "Date is before" option only gives a few options, none of them seem to allow what I'm looking for.  Is there a custom formula that could accomplish this?

Edit:  attaching a snip of the column in question:

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

Formula :

```
=DAYS(now(),B2)>90
```

[image]

Comment: It's not seeming to highlight any cells

Answer (score 0):

Go to the custom formula in the conditional formating rules and use this:

```
=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"D")<90
```

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't seem to highlight any cells  (edit: I did check that they're all formatted as "date")

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=1*C2>DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+3, DAY(TODAY()))
```

[image: 0]

also make sure you have valid dates and not plain text dates. you can test this with `ISDATE` formula

Comment: I just tried this, and it highlights cells, but it almost seems at random... I'm not sure what the pattern is.  It's even highlighting some cells that just contain text

Comment: I added a little picture of the column in question

Comment: @RichF answer updatd

Comment: Just tried this again and it doesn't seem to highlight cells in the column at all.  I didn't realize this would end up being so difficult; I figured a simple date function would be easier

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and a [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) in order to solve your issue with setting the color in the cell depending on the date. Go to ***Tools->Script Editor*** and paste this code:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Check Difference', 'dateDifference')
      .addToUi();
}

function dateDifference(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange(); // Get the selected range on the sheet
  var dates = sheet.getValues(); // Get the values in the selected range
  var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24;
  var row = 1;
  var re = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/; // This will help you to check if it's really a date
  dates.forEach(function(el){ // Iterate over each value
    if(typeof el[0] == 'object'){ // Check if it's really a date
      var gmtZone = el[0].toString().split(" ")[4].split(":")[0]; // Take the date's GMT 
      var dateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(el[0], gmtZone, "dd/MM/yyyy"); // Format the date
      if(re.test(dateFormatted)){ // Test if it's the right format
        // This part will calculate the difference between the current date and the future date
        var futureDateMs = new Date(el[0]);
        var todayDateMs = (new Date()).getTime();                               
        var differenceInMs = futureDateMs - todayDateMs;
        var differenceInDays = Math.round(differenceInMs/oneDay);
        if(differenceInDays >= 91.2501){ // Test if the difference it's greater to 91.2501 days (3 motnhs)
          sheet.getCell(row, 1).setBackground("#00FF00"); // Set the color to the cell
        } 
        row++;
      }
    }
  });
```

Save it by clicking on ***File->Save***.

---

Then you can select a range in a column and click on ***Custom Menu->Check Difference*** as you can see in the next image:
[image]

As you can see, you will get the desired result:
[image]

---

### Notice

It's really important to be careful with what you consider to be a "month", I mean how many days you are going to take into consideration. In my code, I took Google's suggestion of `1 = 30.4167`.
[image]

### Docs

These are other Docs I read to be able to help you:

- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [Working with Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates).

---

I hope this approach can help you.